# Punctuation of Initials in Name

Tags: writing-style, names

My name is *James Lamar Smith*, in which my first name is *James*, middle name is *Lamar* and my last name is *Smith*. I would like to  know which form of my short name is acceptable in English:

1 J. L. Smith (with space after periods)
2 J.L.Smith (without space after periods)
3 J L Smith (without usage of periods)

And my question is: can I omit periods by using space anywhere after using a capitalised letter without periods like *J L Smith*? From *J. L. Smith*? And there is a space after the periods; can we neglect it as in *J.L.Smith*? Could it be used without using space anywhere? Which is acceptable in English for official and agenda use?

Comment: You can write your name anyway you want to. Most people leave a space before the surname.

Comment: For all official purposes, only the first would be acceptable. In other instances like mentioning a name within text, the applicable style guide if any, needs consulted.

Comment: @user Not always, though.

Comment: The first person pronoun is always capitalized in English. See also: [writers.se] and [ell.se]

Comment: Certainly *K. S. Maan* is correct and acceptable in general use, and I doubt that anyone would object to *K.S. Maan*.   I wouldn't recommend *K.S.Maan*, but I wouldn't call it wrong.   The periods/full stops after initials are sometimes omitted; I have seen the equivalent of *K S Maan* used in some scientific journals, for example.  If you're writing for publication, consult the publication's style guide for its preferences in this matter.  Otherwise, suit yourself.

Comment: @tautophile I think K S Maan is Ok for me but i want to know why K.S.Maan can't be used and why K. S. Maan as official but their is space after peroid can we neglect space but can use full stop without space Thanks you and i appreciate your affort and answer for me

Comment: "K.S.Maan" can be used, if you wish, which is why I said I wouldn't call it wrong.  But I don't recommend it.  James Lamar Smith wouldn't write his full name as JamesLamarSmith, after all; he would put spaces between his first, middle, and last names.  He might abbreviate James to J and Lamar to L, and, as is customary, follow those letters with a period/full stop; or he might leave the punctuation out.  But he would normally leave the spaces in, such that he would write either J. L. Smith or J L Smith, not J.L.Smith [no spaces] and probably not J.L. Smith [no spaces between J. and L.]

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/K._S._Makhan On Wikipedia Kuldeep Singh Makhan Is Referred As K. S. Makhan As Well As K S Makhan Since In India British English Is used  i think its good to omit period to write easy your name.

Comment: @tautophile Leaving out the space between initials is exceedingly common; “J.L. Smith” would be a very likely way for James Lamar Smith to write his name. Kris’ statement that only the first option would be acceptable “for all official purposes” is nonsense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Answer**

1. Wikipedia and the NYT write the author's name as [**J. K. Rowling**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._K._Rowling) and [**J. K. Rowling**](https://www.nytimes.com/topic/person/j-k-rowling)
2. The author herself chooses this form, © **J.K. Rowling** and [© **J.K. ROWLING**](https://www.jkrowling.com/) (note the use of block capitals)
3. The Guardian, a British newspaper, favours this form: [**JK Rowling**, author of 15 books…](https://www.theguardian.com/books/2015/nov/28/conversation-lauren-laverne-jk-rowling-interview)

If you're looking at omitting the dot/period, I would personally avoid adding spaces between the initials, e.g. J K Rowling. But people are free to write their name as they please.

**References**
A Wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_literary_initials) of authors whose first and middle names are abbreviated; e.g. D. H. Lawrence, J. D. Salinger, T. S. Eliot, J. R. R. Tolkien, etc. They all follow the same format.

In their manual of style/abbreviations, Wikipedia says [emphasis mine]

> Use initials in a personal name only if the name is commonly written that way. See Wikipedia: *[Manual of Style/Biographies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Manual_of_Style/Abbreviations#Initials)* for when to use full names and other formats.
>
> An initial is followed by a full point (period) and a space (e.g. J. R. R. Tolkien), **unless**:
>
> - **The person had or has a different, consistently preferred style for his or her own name**. In that case: treat as a self-published name change; examples include **k.d. lang** and Jeb Bush.
> - An overwhelming majority of reliable sources do otherwise for that person; examples include **CC Sabathia**.

It seems that the British convention is to omit the dot (period) in names that have initials. The *Independent* has an article about people [whose middle initials are invented](https://www.independent.co.uk/voices/the-top-10-people-with-invented-middle-initials-a7072176.html).  Famous examples include; **Ulysses S Grant**, **Harry S Truman**, **Michael J Fox**, and **JK Rowling**.

Comment: I am British; I write MJ Harvey. My father wrote R.H. Harvey.

Comment: Of course, if you use periods (points, BrE) and do not put in a space, it becomes visually squished and looks awful. Likewise, without periods, you would remove the space. So, this answer is right. What would not be used is: J K Rowling, as you say.

Comment: If someone has his middle name then their must be a space between two initial and in JK Rowling K is even not exists its her grandmother name but in my example J L Smith is used instead of JL Smith to differentiate between two intial so space is used between J and K.